# What should be the input parameters to triangulatePoints in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to find out 3D coordinates using stereo cameras.

For that, I reached up to rectification of images but get stuck at [cv2.triangulatePoints](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints). I find out P1 and P2 using [cv2.stereoRectify](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify). Now I have to put four parameters in `triangulatePoints` functions which are projMatr1 (P1), projMatr2 (P2), projPoints1 and projPoints2.

My first doubt is if P1 and P2 remain same for every pair of images as we are giving input Camera matrices, rotation and translation matrices in `stereoRectify`? According to me, P1 and P2 should be same as none of input matrices are changing.

I want to know how to get `projPoints1`  and `projPoints2` to get 3D coordinates. For example, if I know the pixel values of any point A in rectified left image as (Xl,Yl) and same Point A in right image as (Xr,Yr) can I put `projPoints1 = (Xl,Yl)` and `projPoints2 = (Xr,Yr)` in `triangulatePoints`? If not then how to get these `projPoints`?

Comment: the projPoints are the 2D points in each image that corresponds to each other. The projMatr is the projection matrix, which is intrinsics * extrinsics. StereoRectify will make the epipolar lines parallel, the image is not necessarily the same, you may have to translate it accordingly and crop to be one on one. If you see the image in the example of the documentation you will see what I mean, look at the chair in the right, in one you will see more of the chair than the other one (X wise)

Comment: Thanks @api55 for reply. I  know about rectification and I know that some portion of image get cut but my simple query is : when we used 'R1,R2,P1,P2,Q,validPixROI1, validPixROI2 = cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrixL,distCoeffsL,cameraMatrixR,distCoeffsR,(640,480),R,T,alpha=0)' in this cameraMatrixL, distCoeffsL, cameraMatrixR, distCoeffsR, R and T remain same for all images which we took from same calibrated stereo cameras, then the output matrices should also be same for all these images. I mean R1,R2,P1 and P2 should remain same. As I said in question ....(please see 2nd comment)

Comment: (from 1st comment)..As I said in question that point A lies in both images and I took pixel values of  point A in rectified left image as (Xl,Yl) and same Point A in right image as (Xr,Yr). So , I think  (Xl,Yl) and (Xr,Yr) point is corresponding point only. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Well, R1 and R2 should be obviously different (they rotate the 2 different cameras to be in the same image plane), and the projection matrices can be different as well, since the cameras can have different intrinsics, and even if they have the same intrinsics, the extrinsics are certainly different, if not they are both the same camera in the same position. But if indeed all the parameters you said are exactly the same for all images, it will generate the result.... it is a deterministic function, same input = same output. But it should differ always in the R and T at least

Comment: Also, going to your question in the post, you can put those points in triangulate points, if you know they correspond. To find correspondence you can try to use SIFT or similar to find a match of points, or if both are rectified correctly you can try to match the whole frame, similar to the disparity map [like here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html) and with this map and the intrinsics you can calculate a pointcloud out of it

Comment: Yes, I know that R1 and R2 will be different from each other and P1 and P2 will be different from each other because my intrinsic and extrinsic parameters are not same for both cameras. But my doubt is Let say I have two pairs of images (left1, right1) and (left2,right2). Both these pairs are taken from same stereo calibrated cameras for which R,T,E and F matrices will be same. So, what i want to say is when I put 1st pair (left1,right1) in *cv2.stereoRectify*, it will give R1,R2,P1 and P2. Again, I put 2nd pair of image (left2,right2) in *cv2.stereoRectify* and lets...(please see 2nd comment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154204/discussion-between-naseeb-gill-and-api55).